# Does reducing the Average Waiting Time also reduces the Turnaround Time?

Tags: operating-system, computer-science

My textbook (Galvin) mentions that SJF is optimal in the sense that it has minimal average waiting time. While in the Tanenbaum textbook it is mentioned that it gives the minimal average Turnaround time. 
Also a slide from Stanford mentions that for SJF turnaround time can be sub-optimal.
I am confused whether SJF gives the minimal average waiting time or the minimal average turnaround time or both. 
According to me, turnaround time= waiting time + burst time, so by reducing average waiting time, we do happen to reduce average turnaround time as well.

Comment: Feel free for any queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Yes**. If you are able to reduce the *average waiting time*, then by definition you are also reducing the *average turnaround time*.

***Turnaround Time*** is the time it takes to fullfill a request or total time taken by the process till its completion and therefore, by definition it will include the ***waiting time***. So, if you reduce the ***waiting time*** in the ready queue, you will definitely reduce the ***turnaround Time***.

**SJF** under ideal condition does give minimum *average waiting time*, then why is it not followed?

The answer is **starvation**. If you are considering a system where there is a continuous stream of processes coming in ready queue with **short burst times**, the processes with **large burst times** will never get the **CPU**. They will starve.

If we are **not** considering a system like the above then **yes** SJF gives the minimal *average waiting time* and the *minimal average turnaround time.*

Comment: **Thanks** 
If we consider a scenario where we have some given no.of processes and we have to specify which Scheduling algorithm would give minimal average wait time -  can we definitely say **SJF** ? Or should go for **SRTF** (in case arrival time of processes are different.

Comment: Well , you can always calculate in that case.

Comment: So it depends on the specific numbers and nothing could be stated in general?

Comment: The reason SJF is not followed because it's not implementable as once needs to know the next CPU burst prior and it's not possible to know the next CPU burst before the execution of the process, though we can try to approximate SJF and use it, but it's really not that efficient and hence SJF is used mostly for bench-marking,

Comment: We are talking about the burst time of processes already in the ready queue. Since they are in the ready queue already, we do have fair amount of knowledge of their burst times.